# Can't use GitHub Teams as roles provider for Spinnaker

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, spinnaker

I'm trying to use GitHub as role provider for Spinnaker installation in GCP. I've used https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spinnaker-for-gcp for setting up Spinnaker. For authentication I'm using IAP in GCP and for authorization I want to use GitHUb Teams. I've completed setup from https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authorization/ and https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authorization/github-teams/ but when I'm setting up some restrictions I'm getting locked.
From my perspective it looks like Spinnaker is not able to map user authenticated from IAP with the same user from GitHub. I'm using exactly the same email in both services - Google and GitHub.
Has anyone similar issue? Is my case even possible or I have to use always the same platform for authentication and authorization?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like it is not possible to mix Google IAP with GitHub :(